# How to use context app with a Navigation Container?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, navigation, react-context

I'm trying to create an application to gather some information about plants in React Native with TSX. I want this application to support two languages: English and French. My App.js takes care of displaying the Navigation Container with Drawers. One of my Navigation Container items sends to a window to choose the language. Since I want the language to be supported throughout the application, I had to use the useContext. Except that I have absolutely no way of updating the language context throughout the application from this window.

Thank you very much in advance for your valuable answers !

Here is my code :
App.tsx

```js
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native"
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerItemList } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import FontAwesome6 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import {StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity,} from 'react-native';
import Apropos from './app/AproposView';
import Accueil from './app/AccueilView';
import Langue from './app/LangueView';
import { LangProvider, useLang } from './app/LangContext';
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator()

function App(): JSX.Element {
  const { lang, setLang } = useLang();

  return (
    <LangProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Accueil" component={Accueil} options={{
            drawerLabel: "hello", title: "hello",
            drawerIcon: () => (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log(lang)}>
                <FontAwesome6 name="home" color="#775B45" size={23} />
              </TouchableOpacity>)
          }} />

          <Drawer.Screen name="Langue" component={Langue} options={{
            drawerLabel: "Language : " + lang, title: "Language",
            drawerIcon: () => (<Ionicons name="language" color="#4E894B" size={23} />)
          }} />

          <Drawer.Screen name="Apropos" component={Apropos} options={{
            drawerLabel: "About", title: "About",
            drawerIcon: () => (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="information" color="#345686" size={23} />)
          }} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </LangProvider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});

export default App;
```

LangueView.tsx

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Carreau from './component/Carreau'
import { Dimensions, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import { FlatList, View, StyleSheet, Button, Text, ToastAndroid } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import CarreauList from './component/CarreauList';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
const ITEM_WIDTH = 100; // Largeur d'un carré
const ITEM_HEIGHT = 100; // Hauteur d'un carré
const SPACING = 10; // Espacement entre les carrés
import { useLang } from './LangContext';

export default function Langue(props: any) {

    console.log("LangSelector : on initialise le composant")
    const { lang, setLang } = useLang();

    //fenêtre
    //est-on en landscape ?
    const width = Dimensions.get("window").width;
    const height = Dimensions.get("window").height;
    const isLandscape = width > height;

    //choix des langues
    const langages = [
        {
            id: 0,
            name: "France",
            image: require("../res/image/french_flag.jpg"),
            onclick: () => {
                storeData("language", "fr")
                setLang('fr')
                //props.navigation.navigate('Accueil')
                console.log(lang)
                ToastAndroid.show('Langage défini : Français', ToastAndroid.SHORT)

            }
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "English",
            image: require("../res/image/english_flag.jpg"),
            onclick: () => {
                storeData("language", "en")
                setLang("en")
                console.log(lang)
                //props.navigation.navigate('Accueil')
                ToastAndroid.show('Language changed : English', ToastAndroid.SHORT)
            }
        },
    ];
    return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white" }}>
                <CarreauList list={langages} />
            </View>
    )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        padding: SPACING,
    },
    item: {
        width: ITEM_WIDTH,
        height: ITEM_HEIGHT,
        backgroundColor: "lightgray",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        margin: SPACING / 2,
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 32,
    },
});
```

and my LangContext.tsx :

```js
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, ReactNode } from 'react';

console.log("On définit le type pour les propriétés du contexte")
interface LangContextProps {
  lang: string;
  setLang: (color: string) => void;
}

console.log("ThemeContext : on crée le contexte avec une valeur initiale (par exemple, 'fr')")
//on reprend les mêmes données qu'au dessus
//LangContext devient alors un véritable conteneur
const LangContext = createContext<LangContextProps>({
  lang: 'fr',
  setLang: () => {}, // Fonction par défaut
  
});

console.log("On crée un fournisseur de contexte pour envelopper votre application")
export function LangProvider({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  console.log("ThemeContext : initialisation du fournisseur de contexte")
  const [lang, setLang] = useState('fr');

  //on retourne l'enveloppe avec les mêmes noms de paramètre que le useState du dessus
  return (
    <LangContext.Provider value={{ lang, setLang }}>
      {children}
    </LangContext.Provider>
  );
}

// Utilisez un hook personnalisé pour accéder au contexte
export function useLang() {
  console.log("ThemeContext : useTheme. on retourne le résultat de la fonction useContext(ThemeContext)")
  return useContext(LangContext);
}
```